# Export Excel functionality is not working on azure(huge records only)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

The export  functionality working correctly with out any error in my local environment and only getting error on server environment (Dev,QA).
We solved the same  issue in past using web config in IIS but now we migrated to Azure and facing the same kind of issue on behalf exporting huge records (Azure).

Past IIS code:

Same config code is not working on azure as it set to IIS only

Now we deployed the application to azure and changed the web config in same way but still getting error if record count is greater than 12,500 approx.

```
   <system.webServer>

        <security>

              <requestFiltering>

                    <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000000"/>                    

              </requestFiltering>

        </security>

  </system.webServer>
```

The export  functionality working correctly with out any error in my local environment and only getting error on server environment (Dev,QA).
We solved the same  issue in past using web config in IIS but now we migrated to Azure and facing the same kind of issue on behalf exporting huge records (Azure).

Past IIS code :

Same config code is not working on azure as it set to IIS only

Now we deployed the application to azure and changed the web config in same way but still getting error if record count is greater than 12,500 approx.

```
   <system.webServer>

        <security>

              <requestFiltering>

                    <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000000"/>                    

              </requestFiltering>

        </security>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is the application azure-functions project or web application?

Comment: Web application using .net core 6.0 deployed in github ci pipeline

Comment: Any one help me

Comment: The solution to set the requestLimits tells me that the original problem was that your request was too large. maxQueryString seems to indicate that you are passing a long line of parameters. is this correct?
In your current problem, your get one of the following HTTP status.substatus: 404.14, 404.15, 413.1 431 ?
does your application seems to be working for some minutes and then just fails?

Comment: Yes correct low records it is working fine .

Comment: Yes am passing the long line of parameters only .

Comment: Am getting 404.15 error

Comment: Yes low records i can able to export(7k).huge records 34 k am not able to export

Comment: Could you please share the code of `Export to Excel`.

Comment: `requestFiltering` must contain the  `maxAllowedContentLength`.Add the below code snippets in your `Web.config` file.

Comment: `<system.web>
<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
 </system.web>`

Comment: `<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!--50MB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to read huge `Excel` data.

Thanks @aspsnippets for the Excel Code.

Here I am trying to load the Excel file which contains 15k records.

***Application Folder Structure:***
[image]

- Install the NuGet package `System.Data.OleDb`.

***My `Controller.cs`***

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Excel_Export.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment Environment;
        private IConfiguration Configuration;
        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment _environment, IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            Environment = _environment;
            Configuration = _configuration;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormFile uploadFile)
        {
            if (uploadFile != null)
            {
                //Create a new Folder.
                string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                //Save the uploaded Excel file in the Created Folder.
                string FName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
                string FPath = Path.Combine(path, FName);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    uploadFile.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                string conStr = this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExcelConString");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conStr = string.Format(conStr, FPath);

                using (OleDbConnection conExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter oledbExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmdExcel.Connection = conExcel;
                            conExcel.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                            dtExcelSchema = conExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            conExcel.Close();

                            conExcel.Open();
                            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                            oledbExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                            oledbExcel.Fill(dt);
                            conExcel.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

***My `appsettings.config`:***

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {  
    "constr": "Server=tcp:****.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=****;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30",
    "ExcelConString": "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"
  }
}
```

***`Web.config` file:***

```cs
<system.web> 
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" /> 
</system.web>
```

```cs
<system.webServer> 
    <security>
         <requestFiltering> 
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!--50MB--> 
         </requestFiltering> 
     </security> 
 </system.webServer>
```

Add the above setting in `web.config` file.

I have done `Remote Debugging`.

You can see the count of Excel data in the deployed Azure App Service.

[image]

To avoid issues related to size limits, it is advised to load the Excel file to Azure Blob and read the file from there.